# Convert Spoon model into something else

Tags: java, inria-spoon

I am trying to convert a `Spoon representation` of a Java code into something else ; let say a `JSON` or `XML` representation or into other `Java model`.

I am not sure how and where to start.

- Do I have to write a `processor` for each **leaf** of Spoon's
  metamodel (which is a lot of processors to write)?
- Do I have to write a processor that
  analyse each **Class** and has a top/down approach (which will contain a lot of `instanceof` checks)?
- Do I have to
  write a `Scanner` that is based on a tree-based representation?

Last question: when converting an element (let say a `CtIf`) how identifying its parent (a `CtBlock`) in a unique way?

Let say that it will output the following:

```
[
  {
    type: block,
    id: ???,
    ...,
  },
  ...,
  {
    type: if,
    parent: ???, (the block above)
    ...,
  }
]
```

I am a bit lost and need some help :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to implement a custom pretty-printer (look on https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/blob/master/src/main/java/spoon/reflect/visitor/DefaultJavaPrettyPrinter.java) and to pass it to a Launcher by overriding it.